# How to make Woocommerce product as a Contact form

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

So here's what i'm trying to do. when buyer click on "add to cart" in shop page. it will be directed to single product page. here we remove everything and add a contact form. for example let's say we have a contact form with e entries . First name , Last name and Message fields. and a submit button. so when a buyer fill out those and hit submit button. it places a new woocommerce order (skipping checkout and payment). finally it display woocommerce thank you page. (with order id and form submission data)

i would like to know if you guys think this is possible and please send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think You can do it like, on add to cart click redirect to custom template

1. create custom template with form and also get id of user, order id and product added in cart.
   refer to: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/
2. create another template with thankyou and show desire output.

Note: By creating template you can do your desire coding without modifying default files.